# Query to find duplicates returning excess result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a query intended to find duplicates, specifically on the fields country inc and CompanyRegNum, but the gtid should not be duplicated. When i run the SQL it returns millions of records. I know for a fact that there are not million CompanyRegNums so the query is doing something wrong, but for the life of me i don't know what.

```
 select  distinct
    @reportIdCompRegCompInc   ,
    wp1.CrmPartyId,
    wp1.GtId,  
    convert(varchar(20), 
            hashbytes('SHA1', isnull(wp1.CrmPartyId, '') + isnull(wp1.GtId, 
 '') ), 
            2), 
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'GT ID'),                     
 @WeccoSysId,       wp1.GtId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'CRM Party 
 Id'),              @WeccoSysId,        wp1.CrmPartyId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Legal Name'),                
@WeccoSysId,        wp1.LegalName,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Business 
Class'),            @WeccoSysId,        wp1.BusinessClass,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Relationship 
Manager Name'), @WeccoSysId,        wp1.RmFullName,     
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'PbeName'),                   
@WeccoSysId,        wp1.PbeFullName,            
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Overall 
Status'),           @WeccoSysId,        wp1.OverallStatus,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Country of 
Incorp'),           @WeccoSysId,        wp1.CountryInc,
    (select AttributeId from Reporting.Attribute where Name = 'Company 
 Reg'),               @WeccoSysId,        wp1.CompanyRegNum,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'GT ID'),                     
 @WeccoSysId,       wp2.GtId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'CRM Party 
 Id'),              @WeccoSysId,        wp2.CrmPartyId,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Legal Name'),                @WeccoSysId,        wp2.LegalName,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Business Class'),            @WeccoSysId,        wp2.BusinessClass,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Relationship 
  Manager Name'), @WeccoSysId,        wp2.RmFullName,       
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'PbeName'),                   
 @WeccoSysId,       wp2.PbeFullName,            
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Overall Status'),        @WeccoSysId,        wp2.OverallStatus,
    (select AttributeId from REPORTING.Attribute where Name = 'Country of 
 Incorp'),          @WeccoSysId,        wp2.CountryInc,
    (select AttributeId from Reporting.Attribute where Name = 'Company 
 Reg'),               @WeccoSysId,        wp2.CompanyRegNum

    from        core.WeccoParty         wp1
  join  CORE.WeccoParty wp2                 on  wp1.CompanyRegNum       = 
 wp2.CompanyRegNum
  where wp1.OverallStatus = 'Onboarded'

                                     and wp2.OverallStatus = 'Onboarded'
                                     and wp1.CountryInc = wp2.CountryInc     
                                     and wp1.GtId <> wp2.GtId
                                     and wp1.CompanyRegNum is not null
                                     and wp2.CompanyRegNum is not null
                                     and wp1.CountryInc is not null
                                     and wp2.CountryInc is not null
                                     and wp1.CompanyRegNum NOT IN 
 ('0','.','n.a','n/a','n.a.','00000','unknown','Unknown','000000','00000000')
                                     and wp1.CompanyRegNum NOT LIKE('^0*0$')
```

Comment: Simplify the problem... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are those seriously Line breaks in your literal strings? I would personally use `'CRM Party ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Id'` rather than having a literally line break and/or carriage return in your literal string for things like that. It'll make things a little more readable.

Comment: Probably WeccoParty table has multiple line with same CompanyRegNum.

Comment: All those calls to `REPORTING.Attribute` as subqueries must be a performance killer as well. Have you not considered referring to it once in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: Larnu, like how? Could you please provide an example of what you mean in your last point.

Comment: Difficult to show in comments, but one way might be: `CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN [name] = 'Company' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' Reg' THEN AttributeId END) AS CompanyReg, MAX(CASE WHEN [name] = 'Overall Status' THEN AttributeId END) AS OverallStatus, ... FROM Reporting.Attribute) AS AI`